# Assembly Error on VS continuous delivery at Azure WebApp

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm the administrator of a WebApp and I'm having an strange behavior while using continuous delivery. If I right click site project and choose Publish site works fine, but if I use VisualStudio.com Build and Release I have following problem:

[image: Azure assembly error]

As I said, if I publish site everything is ok. I used Kudu to check files after Release and Storage is at bin folder.

[image: Kudu bin]

Here are some of configs:

[image: csproj file]

[image: web.config]

And here are Build and Release results:
[image: Build result]
[image: Release result]

Comment: Can you share the detail build and release log on the OneDrive (Set/add system variable with true value)?

Comment: Could you please show/provide the Deploy Azure App Service task in your Build/Release pipeline?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a lot I found that WindowsAzure.Storage v9 is not compatible with WebJobs. I just downgrade to V8.1.1 and now is ok.

Comment: How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try adding assembly binding redirects for the Windows Azure StorageClient library.

Reference: http://robertgreiner.com/2012/12/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-windows-azure-storage-client/

Also check this https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/windows-azure-storage-dll-version-mismatch link which has similar issue discussed and check if this  helps.

Also try the below workaround

```html
UnInstall-Package WindowsAzure.Storage
Install-Package Microsoft.Data.Services.Client -Version 5.6.0
Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage
```

Comment: I already tried uninstalling and installing again the assemblies, also using newer and older versions, but I'll try first link solution. Tks